# Several related verbal or phrasal usages

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

> -Obie: They wanna lock you out.
>
> -Tony: Why, cause the stocks dip 40 points? We knew this was gonna happen.
>
> -Pepper: 56 and a half.
>
> -Tony: It doesn't matter. We own a controlling interest in the company.
>
> -Obie: Tony, the Board has rights too. They are **making the case** that you and your new direction isn't in a company's best interest.
>
> -Tony: I'm being responsible. That's a new direction. For me... for the company. I mean, me on the company's behalf being responsible for
> the way that... Oh, this is great!
>
> -Obie: Oh **c'mon**, wait! Tony, Tony!
>
> -Tony: I'll be in the shop.
>
> -Obie: Hey, hey, Tony, listen. I'm trying to turn this thing around but you gotta give me something. Something to **pitch** them. Let me have
> the engineers analyze that, you know, draw some specs.
>
> -Tony: No. No. Absolutely not. This one stays with me. That's it Obie. Forget it.
>
> -- *Iron Man* 2008

Does **making the case** mean **making the arguments**? What components constitute a typical case/argument? Is **c'mon** used here to show that you know what somebody has said is not correct?

Does **pitch** mean **persuade** here? Can I say **pitch somebody something** (ditransitive)? The dictionaries don't give a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *making the case* means making reasons to support what they want to do. I suppose that could be *arguments*. As to what a *case* or *argument* consists of, that would probably be a question you could ask a lawyer.

*c'mon* [(contraction of *Come on!* = exclamation of disbelief)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Xt08AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=%22come%20on%22%20%20%22exclamation%20of%20disbelief%22&source=bl&ots=3k3O51SpO5&sig=mO8MrYHSQvbFQPPSyt3JHuBZmho&hl=en&sa=X&ei=J-muU5alEc7ePfqBgZgF&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22come%20on%22%20%20%22exclamation%20of%20disbelief%22&f=false) basically means something like "wait" or "hold on". He is trying to get Tony's attention to tell him his point of view.

When you are trying to sell something (or some idea in this case) to someone, you can use *to pitch* to describe that action. Check this definition [pitch](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/pitch) senses 6 or 28. In some ways it is a persuasion I suppose.

Comment: I clarified the "expanded" version of *c'mon* because it probably isn't obvious to some non-native speakers. Personally I find the cited *pitch* without *to* (or maybe *at*) a little bit "iffy", but I'm sure it's used.

Comment: Oh, I see. After Obie shows his disbelief he tries to convince Tony by making his case. And, sir, are you suggesting _Something to pitch (to/at) them_? I didn't hear that said in the movie. The scripts didn't show that either. Then it's just colloquial. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I tend to think of *c'mon* as being more literal in a metaphoric sense-  You are "standing" over there with your belief which is so "clearly" unbelievable that you must be sticking to it out of sheer pigheadedness.  "C'mon" (Come on) means we are encouraging you to stop standing over there and to come on over and join us and our "clearly superior" arguments and that if you do we won't hold your initial beliefs against you.

Comment: Very good arguments you got there. You've connected the dots! @Jim

Comment: @Zhanlong: As you probably know, prepositions (and other "non-essential" words) are highly likely to be discarded in particular specialised contexts (especially, *spoken* ones) if they need to be used often in that context. The more general community are often aware of domain-specific slang usages where this happens, but we tend to *keep* the preposition longer because it helps other people recognise that we're referencing a "specialised vocabulary" usage.